# re.search puts end of group(1) options at the beginning of group(2). What's wrong with my construction of the regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to parse paragraphs into data fields based on commonly occurring strings. Here's an example:

```
tstStr = 'Locations of performance are California, North Carolina and Pennsylvania, with a Sept. 14, 2017, performance completion date.'
pperf = '([Ww]ork will be performed [(in)(at)]|[Ll]ocation[(s )\s] of performance [(is)(are)])(.*?)( and (the work )?is expected| with a(.*)completion date)'
pTest = re.search(pperf, tstStr)
```

With the intended result being:

```
pTest.group(2)
California, North Carolina and Pennsylvania,
```

Instead I get:

```
pTest.group(2)
re California, North Carolina and Pennsylvania,
```

How am I incorrectly writing the first group?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that your `[(is)(are)]` is actually a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matching 1 symbol, `(`, `i`, `s`, etc. You need a non-capturing group, `(?:is|are)` that matches either a `is` or `are` *character sequences*.

Use a regex like

```
([Ww]ork will be performed (?:in|at)|[Ll]ocations? of performance (?:is|are))\s*(.*?)( and (the work )?is expected| with a(.*)completion date)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0TvRhq/1)

Comment: Thank you. I had thought parentheses only identified character sequences and brackets identified allowed characters. Is there any difference, then, between what i originally wrote and [isare]?

Comment: `[(]` matches a `(`.  So, `[isare]` != `[(is)|(are)]` that also matches `)`, `|`, `(`